# Join multiple txt files into one file using pd.DataFrame.join()

Tags: python, pandas

I have around 20 tab-delimited files like this:

```
file1.txt
CHROM   POS REF ALT BOB
chrA    15  C   A   0.01
chrA    18  C   A   0.01
chrA    19  C   A   0.01
chrA    27  C   A   0.01

file2.txt
CHROM   POS REF ALT SMITH
chrA    15  C   A   0.01
chrA    16  C   A   0.01
chrA    19  C   A   0.01
chrA    36  C   A   0.01

file3.txt
CHROM   POS REF ALT JOHN
chrA    13  C   A   0.01
chrA    16  C   A   0.01
chrA    19  C   A   0.01
chrA    27  C   A   0.01
```

I want to merge them in order to get this output, so I want to get ALL the occurences in common and not, and if one of the files do not have that occurence put `.` as missing, so to get this output file.

```
CHROM   POS REF ALT BOB SMITH JOHN
chrA    13  C A . . 0.01   
chrA    15  C   A   0.01 0.01 .
chrA    16  C   A   . 0.01 0.01
chrA    18  C   A   0.01 . .
chrA    19  C   A   0.01 0.01 0.01
chrA    27  C   A   0.01 . 0.01
chrA    36  C   A   . 0.01 .
```

This is what I tried, but the reduce step gets `killed`.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
targetdir = "path/to/my/files/"
#list the files
filelist = os.listdir(targetdir) 
my_dfs = [pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t').set_index('POS') for file in filelist]
final_dfs=reduce(lambda l,r: l.combine_first(r), my_dfs)
base_filename = 'out.final.txt'
with open(os.path.join(final_dfs, base_filename),'w') as outfile:
  df.to_string(outfile)
```

Comment: you are trying to join a dataframe with itself

Answer (score 1):

```py
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv, concat
from pathlib import Path

files = Path("files") # path to folder containing all .txt files

if not files.exists():
    raise ValueError("Path does not exist")
    
txt_files = files.glob("*.txt") # getting all txt files
   
result_df = DataFrame()
for txt_file in txt_files:
    df = read_csv(txt_file, delimiter="   ", engine='python')
    result_df = concat([result_df, df])
    
result_df = result_df.fillna('.')
result_df.to_csv('result.txt', sep=" ")
```

#### Output:

```
 CHROM POS REF ALT JOHN SMITH
0 chrA 13 C A 0.01 .
1 chrA 16 C A 0.01 .
2 chrA 19 C A 0.01 .
3 chrA 27 C A 0.01 .
0 chrA 15 C A . 0.01
1 chrA 16 C A . 0.01
2 chrA 19 C A . 0.01
3 chrA 36 C A . 0.01
```

#### Notes:

I worked with only 2 .txt file in my example but it will work with n number of files
files given in example **do not have a common delimiter to it !!**
Just make sure that every word in your txt file is separated by `"   "  i.e 3 blank spaces`  `basically each word given in example is not separated by tab`
**unfortunately pandas does not support exporting DataFrame to csv with more than 1 char long delimiter !!**

this is how your txt should look like:

```
CHROM   POS   REF   ALT   JOHN
chrA   13   C   A   0.01
chrA   16   C   A   0.01
chrA   19   C   A   0.01
chrA   27   C   A   0.01
```

Comment: I saw your solution but I feel like this is better implementation !! :)

Comment: Thank you a lot, but this is giving me a very strange result... not the one I expect, I guess something is going wrong there...I dont have to concatenate but to join and I need to get the output as the example in the question...

Comment: Ok, now I understand this is not joining my files, but concatenating one under another, so I get values in diagonal...